# All of my database User columns are marked as (undefined) Parse.com?

Tags: android, json, parse-platform

This is a strange problem that only started yesterday, and I can't think of anything in my code that would have changed anything. I'm setting up a User on Parse, which includes profile information. Now, for some reason (and I can't find ANYTHING about this particular issue online) when I submit the user profile information, while all of the related fields in the app are correctly retrieving the data from Parse (which means it's out there)... when I look at the User on Parse.com all of the fields are marked as (undefined). This is most likely a JSON error, but I can't figure out where it is coming from? Here's my code for the user to submit their profile... see anything? **I will add... The user has already signed up in another activity preceding this one.**

```
public class CreateProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ParseUser mCurrentUser;
private ParseFile mUserProfilePic;
private EditText mFirstName;
private EditText mLastName;
private EditText mBusinessName;
private EditText mBusinessCategory;
private EditText mBusinessDescription;
private ImageView mProfilePicImageView;
private Button mSubmitInfoButton;
private Uri mProfilePicUri;
private Bitmap mProfilePicBitmap;
private byte[] mProfilePicByteArray;
private boolean mProfilePic = false;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private CirclePhotoTransform mCirclePhotoTransform = new CirclePhotoTransform();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_profile);

    //INITIALIZE ALL UI ELEMENTS...
    mFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstNameField);
    mLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastNameField);
    mBusinessName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.businessNameField);
    mBusinessCategory = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.businessCategoryField);
    mBusinessDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.businessDescriptionField);
    mProfilePicImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicImageView);
    mSubmitInfoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitProfileButton);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.createProfileProgress);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //INITIALIZE PARSE USER
    mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    mProfilePicImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectProfilePicture();
        }
    });

    mSubmitInfoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (mProfilePic) {
                mUserProfilePic = new ParseFile(mCurrentUser.getUsername() + "ProfilePicture.png", mProfilePicByteArray);
                mUserProfilePic.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            submitUserProfile();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(CreateProfileActivity.this, "There was an error. " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                mProfilePicBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mProfilePicImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                mProfilePicBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, stream);
                mProfilePicByteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                mUserProfilePic = new ParseFile(mCurrentUser.getUsername() + "ProfilePicture.png", mProfilePicByteArray);
                mUserProfilePic.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            submitUserProfile();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(CreateProfileActivity.this, "There was an error. " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

}

private void submitUserProfile() {

    DateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String creationDate = formattedDate.format(date);

    mCurrentUser.put("firstName", mFirstName.getText().toString());
    mCurrentUser.put("lastName", mLastName.getText().toString());
    mCurrentUser.put("businessName", mBusinessName.getText().toString());
    mCurrentUser.put("businessCategory", mBusinessCategory.getText().toString());
    mCurrentUser.put("businessDescription", mBusinessDescription.getText().toString());
    mCurrentUser.put("itemsSoldCount", 0);
    mCurrentUser.put("creationDate", creationDate);
    mCurrentUser.put("totalRevenue", "0.00");
    mCurrentUser.put("userProfilePic", mUserProfilePic);

    mCurrentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            goToHomeScreen();
        }
    });
}

private void goToHomeScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CreateProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void selectProfilePicture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 5:
                getProfilePic(data);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

private void getProfilePic(Intent data) {
    mProfilePicUri = data.getData();
    try {
        mProfilePicBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mProfilePicUri);
        mProfilePicBitmap = mCirclePhotoTransform.transform(mProfilePicBitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (mProfilePicBitmap != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mProfilePicBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
        mProfilePicByteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    }
    mProfilePicImageView.setImageBitmap(mProfilePicBitmap);
    mProfilePic = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I haven't figured out why, so if anyone knows why please tell me why. When I switched the value being stored in `mCurrentUser.put("totalRevenue", "0.00");` to `mCurrentUser.put("totalRevenue", 0.00);` which stores as a Number on Parse.com. I'm not sure why storing the value as a String was nullifying everything else that was being stored but it was. After the change, all the data appears and is saved to Parse.com.

Answer (score 0):

Check exactly what's the error .... ur getting

```
public void done(ParseException e) {
     if (e != null) {
        goToHomeScreen();
    }
    else {
       Log.d("Error", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Error: "+e.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```